# Restrictions on drop collections on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to add a restriction when deleting collections that are referenced by id in other collections using `mongodb` or `mongoose`?

I need something like "`on delete restrict`" from `sql` to use on `mongodb`.

Answer (score 0):

References from one collection to another are not explicit. So Mongo has no way to know that an `ObjectId` property in a document refers to the id of another document, nor in which collection. So I believe it's not possible to have such restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support this feature, you can implement in your own application.

Keep a `refcount` field in your document to track referenced count.

```
db.coll.remove({refcount: 0})
```